# ASP.NET MVC 5 Identity 2 PasswordSignInAsync method always returns false

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I'm writing come code that will be for an external app.  I'm trying to use Microsoft Identity 2.0 and ASP.NET MVC 5.  I've customized the UserViewModel to hold FirstName and LastName And a couple of other parameters.  Whenever I register a user it logs in successfully but when I try to do the normal login with email/password.  the **SignInManager.PasswordSignAsync** always returns false. Since all the code that checks that is internal to the framework I'm trying to figure out how to even debug the situation.   I will provide some code here to help anybody who's willing to look at it.  Thanks in Advance!

That is the generic login function that is provided by Microsoft in their examples.  I've not changed anything there. But that is the function that has the error message.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
        // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
        var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
        switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                return View("Lockout");
            case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
            case SignInStatus.Failure:
            default:
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                return View(model);
        }
    }
```

This is the login function

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
        // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
        var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
        switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                return View("Lockout");
            case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
            case SignInStatus.Failure:
            default:
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                return View(model);
        }
    }
```

This is the customized Identity Model

```
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    [DisplayName("Prefix")]
    public string Prefix { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Suffix")]
    public string Suffix { get; set; }

    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }

    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<JBIPlacementTracking.Models.PlacementViewModel> PlacementViewModels { get; set; }

    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<JBIPlacementTracking.Models.Placement> Placements { get; set; }

    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<JBIPlacementTracking.Models.PacketStatus> PacketStatus { get; set; }
}
```

I'm wondering if the problem might be that I don't have a custom LoginViewModel.

I'm definitely in over my head right now and if somebody has some good resources I'd really appreciate a link to it.

Thanks in Advance Again!

Comment: When you added the additional fields to the model, did you create a migration to add those fields to the database?  I wonder if this is related to your model being out of sync with the database rather than a login failure.  The account you created (registered?) does exist in the database?

Comment: I did create the migration.  Also when I query the User Table in SQL Manager they records do show up.   Should I post that here?

Comment: You are using `Email` as `UserName` at the login function. Make sure that on registration, the email is inserted into the `UserName` Field. Also use `Trim()` and `ToLower()` before inserting and after reading.

Comment: @Issac you are correct can you post it as an answer so I can mark it as answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using **Email** as **UserName** then you need to set **EmailConfirmed** field 'true' in **AspNetUsers** table.

Answer (score 5):

You are using `Email` as `UserName` at the login function. Make sure that upon registration, the email is inserted to both the `UserName` and `Email` Fields. I Also like to use use `Trim()` and `ToLower()` before inserting and after reading, but that's only to rest my mind about what is stored in my DB, and might not be necessary. Good luck.

Comment: UserName is case sensitive? Where do you have that info from?

Comment: @SteenTøttrup I guess that`s not entirely correct. Might be something in my own project configuration, or something dragged from my days with Membership. Any way thanks for commenting and i will edit the answer.

Comment: @SteenTøttrup Sny idea regarding to solution?

Comment: Old post, but adding email into the username worked for me.